# Use a constant from a function I'm calling within another function in Swift

Tags: swift, function, parameters

I'm trying to access a variable from another function, but I don't think passing the constant as a parameter will be appropriate since this is an image picker controller. Here's the code I want to pass the constant into:

```
//Get metadata from a photo. Save location (latitude/longitude) to a dictionary.
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // Add delegate
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self


    if let URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        print("We got the URL as \(URL)")
        let opts = PHFetchOptions()
        opts.fetchLimit = 1
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [URL], options: opts)
        for assetIndex in 0..<assets.count {
        var asset = assets[assetIndex]
        let opts = PHFetchOptions()
        opts.fetchLimit = 1
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [URL], options: opts)
        for assetIndex in 0..<assets.count {
            var asset = assets[assetIndex]
            var location = String(describing: asset.location!)
            var photoLatitude = asset.location?.coordinate.latitude
            var photoLongitude = asset.location?.coordinate.longitude
            //var coords : [String: Double]  = ["longitude": photo_longitude!, "latitude": photo_latitude!]
            PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [URL], options: nil)
            dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
            print(photoLatitude)
            print(photoLongitude)
            getAddressFromGoogle(lat: photoLatitude!, long: photoLongitude!)


            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the function containing the constant I need:

```
    // Create function to get an address from Google from latitude/longitude.
    func getAddressFromGoogle(lat: Double, long: Double) {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
        let textLat = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: lat)), textLong = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: long))
        let completeUrl = baseUrl + textLat! + "," + textLong! + urlSuffix
        Alamofire.request(completeUrl, method: .get).responseJSON {
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print("Successful request.")

                var locationData = JSON(response.result.value!)
                // Parse the result for "formatted_address" inside of the entire results block
                let streetAddress = locationData["results", 0, "formatted_address"]
                print(streetAddress)
                print(completeUrl)


            }

            else {
                print("Error \(response.result.error)")

            }
        }

    }
```

I want to give my image picker controller access to the streetAddress constant. What's the best way to approach this in Swift?

Comment: You can use completion handler/callback for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad for the asynchronous side. So you need to add a completion block closure as a parameter on your `func getAddressFromGoogle(lat: Double, long: Double, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void)` like this :

```
func getAddressFromGoogle(lat: Double, long: Double, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
 let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
 numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
 let textLat = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: lat)), textLong = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: long))
 let completeUrl = baseUrl + textLat! + "," + textLong! + urlSuffix
 Alamofire.request(completeUrl, method: .get).responseJSON {
     response in
     if response.result.isSuccess {
         print("Successful request.")

         var locationData = JSON(response.result.value!)
         let streetAddress = locationData["results", 0, "formatted_address"] 
         //Here is calling completion block handler to indicate that the treatment is over 
         completion(streetAddress)
    }
    else {
        print("Error \(response.result.error)")
    }
  }
}
```

Then when it's time to call this function in your picker controller function you have to do something like this :

```
getAddressFromGoogle(lat: photoLatitude!, long: photoLongitude!, completion: 
  {(streetAddress) in 

  })
```

And there in the closure you will have access to your constant that you previously passed on your completion handler.

Comment: I had to change the parameter to `completion: @escaping(String) -> Void', without the square brackets. I also had to convert my streetAddress to a string before accessing it within the closure. Aside from that, this is a great solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Alright and you are welcome and keep on mind this completion handler model

Answer (score 0):

The `streetAddress` constant is defined inside a block, so it is not visible outside the same block.
You can define it at a level embedding the functions which need to access it: `getAddressFromGoogle` and `imagePickerController`.

```
let streetAddress = ...
func imagePickerController {
    ...
}
func getAddressFromGoogle(lat: Double, long: Double) {
    ...
}
```